# Keeping the z-statistic while kriging within ArcGIS Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, interpolation, kriging, z-value

I am creating a model that accepts in a .csv file and plots the XY points on a calculated field. The preferred interpolation method is kriging, and when I try to update the z-value field, the parameter will not stick (just goes blank).

Is there anything I am doing wrong? I want to keep the z-value static as it will never change, but the model builder will not keep the static z-value input.

[image]

Any ideas???